# Prism V2 not working with Silverlight 3.0

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, prism, prism-2

I am currently doing a silverlight application with Prism v2. But when I am adding the reference dlls two dlls are not recoganised.

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll &
Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll
```

Can any one give a solution for this?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "not recognised".

Comment: The title says Prism V2, but the text says v3. I'm assuming you mean v2 since that is the latest release and v3 is only in the source tree.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource I've found on getting the Prism for Silverlight stuff up and running is [this post on the Sparkling Client on downloading and building prism](http://www.sparklingclient.com/downloading-and-building-prism/).

Follow that guide and it will give you the location of the correct Silverlight version of the dlls which is what you need [as Richard points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1630045/prism-v2-not-working-with-silverlight-3-0/1630702#1630702).

Answer (score 1):

There is a new version of Prism V2. You can download it from Microsoft site:

"New Composite Application Guidance for WPF and Silverlight 3.0 - October 2009 Released"

Get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=387c7a59-b217-4318-ad1b-cbc2ea453f40)

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm pretty sure Prism was written for use with Silverlight 2.0 so you may encounter other problems.  The [CodePlex forum](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/List.aspx?TagName=Prism%20v2%20-%20Silverlight%203) for Prism has several posts on the subject.

Comment: Prism V2 should be fully compatible with SL3.

Comment: That's good news.  I seem to recall there were a few issues around the time SL3 was out but maybe I misread the posts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the Silverlight versions of those two assemblies. You should be able to find them in the Reference Implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Prism 2 on a Silverlight 3 project in Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 and it works fine. Check that you aren't mistakenly trying to use the wrong assemblies (the WPF ones maybe?)